# IBM App ID: What are the parameters to configure custom encryption during provisioning?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-appid, key-protect

I know how to create an [App ID instance using the IBM Cloud browser UI](https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/app-id), or via CLI and even [utilizing Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/IBM-Cloud/ibm/latest/docs/resources/resource_instance). But what are the parameters for Terraform (and the [Resource Controller API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/resource-controller/resource-controller#create-resource-instance)) to specify that a root key from my Key Protect instance should be used for encryption?

It seems that a parameter for the KMS instance and one for the root key are required. But what's their name?

[image: App ID with custom encryption]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an App ID instance with custom encryption in the browser UI, then retrieved the details using the CLI with `--output JSON`:

[image: parameters in metadata]

The above parameters indicate the required parameters to be passed on the CLI / API / Terraform.

- kms_info: a JSON object with the KMS (Key Protect or Hyper Protect Crypto Services) ID and an url field.
- tek_id: The actual CRN for the crypto key.

Answer (score 0):

I got it running with this configuration (simplified)

```
resource "ibm_resource_instance" "key_protect_instance" {
  name              = "name-your-kp-instance"
  resource_group_id = data.ibm_resource_group.resource_group.id
  service           = "kms"
  plan              = "tiered-pricing"
  location          = local.ibm_region
}

resource "ibm_kms_key" "appid_root_key" {
  instance_id   = ibm_resource_instance.key_protect_instance.guid
  key_name      = "appid-root-key"
  standard_key  = false
  endpoint_type = "private"
}

resource "ibm_iam_authorization_policy" "appid_kms" {
  source_service_name         = "appid"
  target_service_name         = "kms"
  target_resource_instance_id = ibm_resource_instance.key_protect_instance.guid
  roles                       = ["Reader"]
}

resource "ibm_resource_instance" "appid_instance" {
  name              = "name-your-appid-instance"
  resource_group_id = data.ibm_resource_group.resource_group.id
  service           = "appid"
  plan              = "graduated-tier"
  location          = local.ibm_region
  parameters = {
    kms_info = jsonencode({
      id = ibm_resource_instance.key_protect_instance.guid
      url = "https://${local.ibm_region}.kms.cloud.ibm.com"
    })
    tek_id = ibm_kms_key.appid_root_key.crn
  }
}
```

I made an issue for the missing documentation: https://github.com/ibm-cloud-docs/appid/issues/392#issuecomment-1534269880